# How to import multiple csv files selecting only the columns I want depending on the csv files in Python

Tags: python, csv, import, multiple-columns

How to import multiple csv files choosing only the first column in the first csv file and choosing only the second columns for the remaining csv files?

Here is what I've done so far:
After I import multiple csv files using `glob`:

```py
all_files = glob.glob('*.csv')
```

I used the below code to extract only the second columns from all the imported
csv files:

```py
def read_1st(col):
    return pd.read_csv(col, usecols=[1])
```

However, how do I selectively import only the first column in the first csv file and only import the second column for the remaining csv files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the first .csv seperatly from other .csv`s and then 
define a function to return only the first row as you did:

```
def read_csv(col):
   return pd.read_csv('col',usecols[0])

def read_csv_second(col):
   return pd.read_csv('col',usecols[1])

df1=read_csv(col)
df2=read_csv_second(col)
```

After that you can concat them together to get the result:

```
df=pd.concat([df1,df2])
```